# Open A image When the site loads

Tags: media

How to open a image when the site loads like in [this](http://zeetv.com) site. Can this be done wtih lightbox or colorbox

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Drupal answers. This kind of questions is off-topic as per [FAQ]: "Implementing a functionality, or a layout, seen in a site for which only a screenshot, or the site URL is provided."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Splashify](http://drupal.org/project/splashify) module for this

> Display a splash page anywhere on your site by redirecting the user, showing a lightbox, or displaying a popup. This module is designed to be search engine friendly, mobile device friendly and offers multiple configuration options.

Otherwise you can try with lightbox and custom scripts an [example](http://frankleng.me/2010/07/21/drupal-tip-lightbox-pop-up-on-page-load/) is given here